# localized routes solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, routes, t4mvc

I built a french/english app and I would like to use the same controller/view for both language but to have a different route that is map to the current language. Let say I have `website.com/Account/Register` that return to my Account controller and Register action, I would love to have a route that is `website.com/Comptes/Inscription`. I know that I can add a custom route in the RegisterRoute section like so :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "AccountFr", // Route name
                "comptes/inscription", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

But it will need a lot of [boring] code to write all the possibles routes and also, I think it won't work when I will use T4MVC as `@Url.Action(MVC.Account.Register())` will return /Account/Register no mater if I'm in french or in english.

Anyone as suggestions/ideas for this problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Since it does not seem to have a good solution using T4MVC does anyone have an other good solution?

Comment: So do you expect the controller to behave the same way, or do different things? i.e. are the two routes completely identical in term of behavior?

Comment: Same problem here... any solution?

Comment: @Subgurim, I still have not found a good solution, let me know if you do!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this won't easily work with T4MVC. The root of the problem is that when going through T4MVC, you can't pick a specific route. Instead, the route gets selected based on the Controller, action and parameters.